# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.3

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
- A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
- Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
- Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.3.

This is my android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.3'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

This my android\app\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.shop_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And then i have gotten error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.3/google-services-4.2.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.3/google-services-4.2.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have stuck on it. Please help me to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version  `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.3'` **doesn't** exist.

You can use one of these:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: nice catch it should be 4.3.3

Comment: thank you! It is good solution and it work for me. but when i run my app it got error like that> code: "sign_in_failed", details: null, message: "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: ". what is the error?

Comment: @LornTitya It is a different issue and it is related with the login.I suggest you opening a new question with all details. In this way other users can help you.